# Show output in a range of codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in sql server 2008 and below is the snapshot of my table in the database.

[image]

Now I want to see how many school codes are in range of each `Bstart` and `BEnd` codes.

The required ouptut is like this

[image]

I need query that can help me achieve this. I have idea that it is done using "between" in query but don't know how I can implement in this scenario.
Sorry about the formatting of pictures.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: It’s not clear from the data where the count comes from. There’s only one row with each Bstart and Bend, so where can it be determined?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the count actually are the school codes in the range of each BStart and Bend codes

Comment: But how does it come from that? What’s the formula to determine it?

Comment: count is a new column that will hold the number of school code coming in the range. It is a sample of output I made in excel

Comment: @zainulabidin  You realise there are no overlaps in your data?  There is currently no way to aggregate what you have given us into your desired output.  You have missed some important information in your question and until you add it we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appears to want `subquery` as per

> I want to see how many school codes are in range of each Bstart and BEnd codes.

```
select Bstart, BEnd,
       (select count(1) 
        from table t1 
        where t1.Bstart >= t.Bstart and 
              t1.BEnd <= t.BEnd
       ) as Count
from table t
group by Bstart, BEnd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and sample data suggest that you simply want `group by`:

```
select bstart, bend, count(*)
from t
group by bstart, bend;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then you should consider providing better sample data and a better explanation of what you really want to accomplish.